# Updated to Eoan today, stuck with weird dead keys

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout

For various reasons, I decided quite some time ago that dead keys on my keyboard were more of a hassle than a boon, for my usage patterns. So I've been happily using the following settings on my Ubuntu machine:

```
$ cat /etc/default/keyboard
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE
# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="be"
XKBVARIANT="nodeadkeys"
XKBOPTIONS="compose:rctrl"
BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Earlier today, I upgraded from Disco to Eoan and I now find myself with dead keys again. Except this time it seems to be some sort of Gnome dead keys setting?

Whenever I type a tilde or backtick I get this:

[image]

It gets printed, underlined and then waits for further input. So once again I need to type two tildes if I want an actual tilde...

How and where can I disable this?

**EDIT:**

A few important precisions:

1) I do not run the Gnome desktop, I use Awesome

2) `setxkbmap -query` gave me the following answer:

```
enter rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     be
options:    compose:rctrl
```

The compose key comes from a `gnome-tweaks` setting I had changed, but clearly my current xkbmap is wrong.

3) Assuming that Gnome had reset its configuration somehow, I logged out of my Awesome session and started a regular Ubuntu (ie. Gnome) session. Which is correctly using the nodeadkeys variant keyboard!

So it's not Gnome that's doing this. And since it's not only in my terminal but also in Firefox, it's not going to be in my bash startup files. I'm off to dig through the X startup files...

Comment: Did `/etc/default/keyboard` change in connection with the upgrade?

Comment: No, not at all.

Answer (score 0):

In "Settings", go to the "Region & Language" tab. Click the line marked with "+" under "Language Sources" to add another input source. Look for "Dutch (Belgium)" or "French (Belgium)" depending. Clicking on your entry reveals variations of the layout. For "Dutch  (Belgium)", for example, this includes a layout "Belgian (no dead keys)". You can switch between installed layouts using an icon that appeared in the top bar or with a hotkey (by default <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>). Alternatively, you can revert to a single layout by deleting the layout you do not use (click the Trash symbol next to the Input Source in the "Region & Language" diolog.)

If you [do not see a layout](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1739948) you are looking for, it may help to issue the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources show-all-sources true
```

and restarting Gnome Shell.

Comment: Excellent answer, except it's not relevant to my case, see my edit. Thanks anyway.